# jQuery hide/show short delay

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, hide, show

A show/hide jQuery script. When I hide my `div` content and reload the page, my content stays visible for 1 second or something and after this "short delay" everything if fine, my `div` content is hidden.

How can I solve this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#animate_shoutboxTurnOn').hide();
jQuery('#animate_shoutbouxMarker').click(function () {
      jQuery(this).hide();
      jQuery('#shoutbox_category').fadeOut('fast');
      jQuery('#animate_shoutboxTurnOn').show(); 
      jQuery.cookie("openclose","closed", {expires: 365});
      return false;
    });
jQuery("#animate_shoutboxTurnOn").click(function () {
      jQuery(this).hide();
      jQuery('#shoutbox_category').fadeIn('fast');
      jQuery('#animate_shoutbouxMarker').show();
      jQuery.cookie("openclose","open", {expires: 365});
      return false;
    });
if(jQuery.cookie("openclose") == "closed") {
        jQuery("#animate_shoutbouxMarker").hide();
        jQuery("#animate_shoutboxTurnOn").show();
        jQuery('#shoutbox_category').hide();
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css add:

```
#animate_shoutboxTurnOn, #animate_shoutbouxMarker, #shoutbox_category{
    display:none;
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(jQuery.cookie("openclose") == "closed") {
        jQuery("#animate_shoutboxTurnOn").show();
        jQuery("#animate_shoutbouxMarker").hide();
        jQuery('#shoutbox_category').hide();
    } else {
        jQuery("#animate_shoutboxTurnOn").hide();
        jQuery("#animate_shoutbouxMarker").show();
        jQuery('#shoutbox_category').show();
    };
    jQuery('#animate_shoutbouxMarker').click(function () {
      jQuery(this).hide();
      jQuery('#shoutbox_category').fadeOut('fast');
      jQuery('#animate_shoutboxTurnOn').show(); 
      jQuery.cookie("openclose","closed", {expires: 365});
      return false;
    });
    jQuery("#animate_shoutboxTurnOn").click(function () {
      jQuery(this).hide();
      jQuery('#shoutbox_category').fadeIn('fast');
      jQuery('#animate_shoutbouxMarker').show();
      jQuery.cookie("openclose","open", {expires: 365});
      return false;
    });


});
```

Comment: Is not working.. i mean. So, i want to display already my div box and when i click on hide button to hide the box, and when i refresh i want to be hidden and only my hide (show button) to be visible (to toggle on again my box).

Comment: Look at your javascript console, and check for errors.  It sounds like `jQuery.cookie` isn't loaded.

Comment: I have no errors.. everything its okay.. but when the box is hidden and i refresh the page, the box is visible and after a very short delay (1sec) => hidden.. i dont know why.

Comment: The challenge is that the initial state for the box is visible. For this to work right you have to have it hidden, or you have to have a container div above those elements hidden eg `display:none;` then inside `$(document).ready()` you have to show them.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
.hide();
```

with

```
.css('display','none');
```